# How to format an IBM data library into a command prompt window so that it's readable (to a human)?

Tags: vb.net

Ok, here's my Code:

```
Imports IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries

Module ConsoleData1
Sub Main()

    'program identifier (to verify that you're using the right module)
    Console.WriteLine("ConsoleData1.vb")

    'create the connection object to the IBM i
    Using cn As New iDB2Connection("DataSource=xxxxxxxxxxxxx")
        Try
            cn.Open()
        Catch ex As iDB2Exception
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred on cn.Open()")
            Exit Sub
        End Try

        'create a command object, initialize to valid SQL statement
        Using cmd As New iDB2Command("select * from testlib.finishk", cn)

            'create a command object, initialize to valid SQL statement
            Console.Write("Enter the Color Code!==>")
            Dim baldue = Console.ReadLine()

            Dim sql As String = "Select * from testlib.finishk where FINCOD >=" & FINCOD


            Using cmdx As New iDB2Command(sql, cn)
            End Using

            'create a data reader object, fill by executing the command
            Try
                Using dr As iDB2DataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

                    'display data in a table
                    Console.Write("FINCOD" & vbTab)
                    Console.Write("FINDES" & vbTab)

                    While dr.Read()
                        Console.Write("{0}{1}", dr("FINCOD"), vbTab)
                        Console.Write("{0}{1}", dr("FINDES"), vbTab)
                    End While
                End Using

            Catch ex As iDB2Exception
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred on cmd.ExecuteReader()")
                Exit Sub
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to end")
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Sub HandleError(ByVal errorOccurred As String, ByVal ex As iDB2Exception)

    Console.WriteLine(errorOccurred)
    Console.WriteLine("Source: {0}", ex.Source)
    Console.WriteLine("SQLState: {0}", ex.SqlState)
    Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", ex.Message)
    Console.WriteLine("MessageCode: {0}", ex.MessageCode)
    Console.WriteLine("MessageDetails: {0}", ex.MessageDetails)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Private Function Screen() As Object
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Function

End Module
```

Now, how would I make it so that I can resize the cmd window to be larger and still retain the integrity of the table structure?  If I resize the cmd window, it ends up looking like someone just threw the values into a window in random placement.

Thanks.

Comment: Ahh! String concatenation from user input to an sql command! Evil!

Answer (score 1):

You need two things: a line break between each record and length information in your format string (to shoot for fixed width columns).

```
'You can play the -30 numbers here to get different spacing, based on the nature of your data
Dim recordFormat As String = "{0,-30} {1,-30}"

Console.WriteLine(recordFormat, "FINCOD","FINDES")
While dr.Read()
    Console.WriteLine(recordFormat, dr("FINCOD"), dr("FINDES"))
End While
```

Finally, I'm not familiar with DB2, but please tell me there's a better way than string concatenation to add the user's FINDCOD value to the sql statement? What you're doing is horribly unforgivably insecure. What if I put the text `0;DROP TABLE testlib.finishk;--` into your system instead of a FINDCOD? Any sane code would use parameterized queries for this.

Comment: I'm planning on replacing the SQL once I get things operational. Even though, the machine that is housing the DB referenced is only accessible on the internal network, and has zero exposure to the internet.  In the process of learning RPG and VB simultaneously.

I'm an extreme newbie to coding but, I've already read thoroughly on SQL injection methods, such as "1=1". I'll give this a try and let you know how it goes. Thank you

Comment: **DO NOT WAIT UNTIL YOU GET IT OPERATIONAL TO FIX THE SQL**. It doesn't matter that this is internal only, and you'll find that once it's operational you suddenly have no time to fix things like that.

Comment: Any reason you can think of that I shouldn't be calling stored SQL procedures instead?

Comment: Stored procedures help, but they are still vulnerable if you still build a string to pass parameters to them.